# divs instead of using table-tds

Tags: css, css-float

I need to work on data elements with div's without using table - tds. I want to display all divs one by one without break down. If the divs touches the browser edges, scrollbar should come. can you suggest me?
Please check the link - http://jsfiddle.net/VY978/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `float` you can use `display:inline-block` with the combination of `white-space`. Write like this:

```
.mainBox{padding:3px;border:2px solid blue;overflow:hidden;white-space:nowrap;}
.content{
    width:100px;
    border:1px solid red;
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline;/* For IE7*/
    *zoom:1;/* For IE7*/
    white-space:normal;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/VY978/4/

Comment: may i know why *this stands for?

Comment: Paven the `*` is used as a hack to target only the IE7 browser. All other browsers ignore the lines.

Answer (score 1):

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/VY978/2/).

CSS:

```
.mainBox{padding:3px;border:2px solid blue;overflow:scroll;white-space: nowrap;}
.content{width:100px;border:1px solid red;display:inline-block;}​
```

html:

```
<div class="mainBox">
    <div class="content">yes</div>
    <div class="content">yes</div>
    <div class="content">yes</div>
    <div class="content">yes</div>
    <div class="content">yes</div>
    <div class="content">yes</div>
    <div class="content">yes</div>
    <div class="content">yes</div>
    <div class="content">yes</div>
    <div class="content">yes</div>
    <div class="content">yes</div>
    <div class="content">yes</div>
    <div class="content">yes</div>
    <div class="content">yes</div>
    <div class="content">yes</div>
</div>​
```

Answer (score 0):

try this in your css

> .mainBox{padding:3px;border:2px solid blue;overflow:scroll;}
>   .content{width:100px;border:1px solid red;margin-top:2px; }